# Planck constant equation question

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, si-units

I’ve had a lot of contradicting answers around this equation and I want to know if it’s hypothetically correct. I know Planck constant isn’t a force but I want to know if this equation is correctly written in terms of units.

(J * s)(J* s)/m^2 = N^2 * s^2 = N * kg * m

Is the unit conversion correct and does the equation work (disregarding Planck constant units aren’t a force).

Comment: What is $r$ ? If it is a symbol for a variable, the result of lhs assumes that the rhs consists only of units, however $r$ does not seem to be a unit. So it is inconsistent.

Comment: @frederic thomas It’s suppose to be meters. I accidentally put r as radius, I’ll fix it now.

Comment: The unit conversion is correct. But what do you mean with Planck's equation? There are many equations which contain  Planck's constant. Better you add the equation to your post.

Comment: @frederic thomas I may of used the wrong terminology (I’m new to physics). I was mentioning the equation I posted since I was using Planck constant units of J * s .

Comment: Then you get on the rhs a quantity whose units is that of momentum^2.

Comment: *does the equation work* What do you mean by that? Writing the same unit in different ways isn’t particularly useful.

Comment: The title is confusing.

Comment: *I’ve had a lot of contradicting answers around this equation* Such as what? Where? By whom?

Comment: @G. Smith by redditors. Reddit is terrible lol. They said this equation doesn’t work because I ‘can’t calculate a force that isn’t a force’. Not sure what they meant by that but if the equation works in terms of units then I don’t know what the issue was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is the unit conversion correct and does the equation work (disregarding Planck constant units aren’t a force).

The unit conversion
$$\frac{(\mathrm{J-sec})^2}{m^2}=(\mathrm{N-sec})^2$$

Is correct!

Now you can write Planck constant like
$$h=....\mathrm{J-sec}=......\mathrm{N-m-sec}$$

There is nothing wrong with it But there is no reason one will bother to write like that.

---

You can write force in terms of Planck constant. Suppose a stream of photons striking on a wall. We want to know the pressure. It's turn out to be (for normal incidence)

$$P=\frac{F}{A}=\frac{2I}{c}=\frac{2\dot{N}h\nu}{c}$$

Comment: Thank you! I’m a bit new to physics so are those em-dash looking symbols suppose to represent multiplication? In addition, can N^2 * s^2 be simplified as kg^2 * m^2 / s^4 ? And just for extra reference, why is it bad to write it out like that to explain the force between two Planck constant units?

Comment: Yes, those dashes are just for multiplication. There is nothing wrong with going from one unit to another, write Planck in the unit of, say, Pascal, it doesn't matter. But I think the unit should give a sense of what quantity is about. Force is related to mass and acceleration so it's nice to write it in terms of kg, m, and sec. while Planck constant introduces first in term of quanta so it's better to relate it with the energy of photon and so joule is better.

Comment: That makes sense. I know it’s a bit of a side question but is there a simpler way to write N^2 * s^2 ? I had kg^2 * m^2 / s^4 but I’m not sure if this is correct. Am I simplifying it correctly? Thanks for your help again too!

Comment: $N^2-sec^2=Kg^2-m^2-sec^{-4}-sec^2=Kg^2-m^2-sec^{-2}$

Comment: That $-$ means subtraction. You can use \cdot to get a centered dot for multiplication, such as in N$\cdot$m$\cdot$s.

Comment: Ah yes! Actually, I want to use a little small dash. $$N\mbox{-}m\mbox{-}sec$$